# split dataframe column header and values into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, azure-machine-learning-service

I've uploaded my `csv` file on Azure, but for some reason it became like this

```
 nominal;data;curs;cdx         Column 1
0          1;21.06.2000;28  2300;ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
1          1;22.06.2000;28  2200;ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
2          1;23.06.2000;28  1900;ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
3          1;24.06.2000;28  1700;ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
4          1;27.06.2000;28  1300;ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
5          1;28.06.2000;28  1100;ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
```

Basically instead of four columns `nominal`, `data`, `curs`, `cdx` I got two columns with one having all the values and the last one (it is empty or something because the last column has encoding issue) - no idea what.

I have deleted the column `Column 1` like this

```
import pandas as pd

def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
    dataframe1.drop(['Column 1'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
    print('Input pandas.DataFrame #1:\r\n\r\n{0}'.format(dataframe1))
    return dataframe1,
```

How to split the first column into multiple now? To get 4 separate columns

I am using pandas 0.18

Comment: the thing is that I load dataset via python but using azure itself

Comment: Try ````dataframe1['Column 1'].str.split(expand=True)````

Comment: @xyzjayne did nothing `dataframe1['nominal;data;curs;cdx'].str.split(expand=True)`

Comment: Ughh, split(';',expand=True)

Comment: `dataframe1['nominal;data;curs;cdx'].str.split(';',expand=True)` still nothing. But I guess I have to do something with headers first considering that they have to be splitted too, because it returns `nominal;data;curs;cdx
[Information]         0          1;21.06.2000;28`

Comment: This wouldn't change the dataframe in place though. Are you sure you are assigning this to a new variable?

Comment: @xyzjayne oh! no. I thought it as with drop affects the existing

Comment: @xyzjayne yeah, it did the job. How to assing the headers to it then?

Comment: I guess you can just split the string ````'nominal;data;curs;cdx'```` using ordinary string split: ````col_headers = 'nominal;data;curs;cdx'.split(';')```` and then ````dataframe1.columns = col_headers````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the column with:

```
dataframe1['nominal;data;curs;cdx'].str.split(';',expand=True)
```

Then change the headers with:

```
dataframe1.columns = 'nominal;data;curs;cdx'.split(';')
```